# MySQL, can't see my schema's tables in the navigator

Tags: mysql, schema

i'm new to MySQL.
I just created a database and i do not get problem while running it.
The problems come when i want to query it so i create another connection (?) but the navigator on schemas doesn't see any tables, or in the best case just the first one.
Yes i did refresh it a plenty of time.

Thank you anyway and have a nice day.

Comment: Hi, you should add a photo or more information for helping you to understand what you saying to us.

Comment: Hi, thank you i already solved it !